What does "filling a vessel with virtue" mean in this quote of Phillips Brooks?
Could anyone please help me understand this quote of Phillips Brooks from the self-help book "Pushing to the front, Chapter LXVI: Rich without money" by Orison Swett Marden:

"A man may as soon fill a chest with grace, or a vessel with
virtue," says Phillips Brooks, "as a heart with wealth."

Thanks

They're metaphors. It's hard to say what they specifically mean without more context.

a chest and a vessel hold objects: A wooden chest, for example. A pewter vessel, for example. Please look things up before asking.

Grace and virtue are not qualities that can be measured by volume.

One of the definitions of "vessel" is "a container (such as a cask, bottle, kettle, cup, or bowl) for holding something". "Virtue" is "a particular moral excellence; a commendable quality or trait"
Virtue is not a physical object or substance, so it cannot be placed inside a container in the material world. Filling a vessel with virtue is an example of an impossible action, an unattainable goal.

@SaeedVrz (And, that means the main point of the sentence, is that it is equally impossible to "fill" a heart with wealth. Of course Brooks is still speaking in metaphors, because the human heart is a physical object, and so is wealth often, but he's using the common pattern of "heart" to mean "our innermost feelings," and "fill" to mean "be satisfied." I.e., even with wealth, our hearts will "feel empty.")
